# Import/Sync data from third party API to Laravel application

Tags: php, rest, laravel, import, eloquent

I'm currently working on an Laravel 5.2 application which has a `Customer` model which has various relations to other models. Also I have a third party app which manages customers and allows me to obtain their data via their REST API. Because I don´t want to manage duplicate data, my application should be able to import the data from the third party app, but not the other way round (my app adding data to third party) because my app could have customers that should not be present at the third party app.

I thought about a schema like this:

```
<?php
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    // ... other relevant attributes (address, phone, etc)
    $table->boolean('is_foreign') // Flag weather the data comes from a foreign source
    $table->integer('foreign_id') // The id on the third party app
});
```

And then I would have something like an autocomplete javascript for my customer creation form which presents the user the available customers from the third party app and if the user selects a foreign entry, toggles `is_foreign` on creation.
For keeping up to date I would have the Laravel scheduler run every day and update the foreign data if needed.

But I have a feeling that there is or should be a more elegant solution to this problem and so I wan't to know, what could be the pitfalls of this solution and does anyone know a better way to do this.